# Format variable number of decimals

Tags: c#

How can I format a number with a variable number of digital places?

```
var value = 123.456789;
var number = $"{value:F3}";
```

Will give me 123.456

But I don't want to hardcode the digital places to 3, I want to vary it.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I don't want to hardcode the digital places to 3, I want to vary it"_

Comment: Based on a variable. So I want to replace the '3' with a variable

Comment: `var number = value.ToString($"F{n}");`

Comment: or was your question aimed at specifically using the `$"{...}` notation? like in the comment by @DmitryBychenko ? In this case I just found a 3 duplicate. Should fit also now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `string.Format` like this:

```
var decPlaces = 3;
var value = 123.456789;
var number = string.Format("{0:F" + decPlaces  + "}", value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = 3;
var value = 123.456789;
var number = value.ToString("F" + d);
```